# my model does not load in the controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

This is my controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('User_model');
$this->load->helper(array('form','text','url','array'));
$this->load->library(array('Form_validation','email','session'));
}

public function index()
{

$this->model->insert_item();
$this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
}
```

This is my model:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_model extends CI_Model {
public function insert_item()
{
echo "hi";
}
}
```

when i call the model function but it does not load it show error Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_item() on a non-object

Comment: Remember, we use model only to do database operation,

Comment: @Ukasyah - that's not true. You can use model for any data handling situations (like retrieving data from xml or json).

Answer (score 4):

You need to call $this->user_model, [that's the CI pattern](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) to objects mounted:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->load->helper(array('form','text','url','array'));
$this->load->library(array('Form_validation','email','session'));
}

public function index()
{

$this->user_model->insert_item();
$this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
}
```

[Loading a Model](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Your models will typically be loaded and called from within your controller methods. To load a model you will use the following method:

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

If your model is located in a sub-directory, include the relative path from your models directory. For example, if you have a model located at application/models/blog/Queries.php you’ll load it using:

```
$this->load->model('blog/queries');
```

Once loaded, you will access your model methods using an object with the same name as your class:

```
$this->load->model('model_name');

$this->model_name->method();
```

If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading method:

```
$this->load->model('model_name', 'foobar');

$this->foobar->method();
```

TIP Unrelated to the question: Avoid call all the basic helpers on construct, put It on autoload.

Comment: Pay attention to $this->model->insert_item(); it's $this->user_model->insert_item() !!

Comment: And avoid call all the basic helpers on construct, put It on autoload

Answer (score 0):

open your autoload.php file in

> application/config/autoload.php
>   add

```
$autoload['model'] = array('user_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax. Here is the documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

This is the correct way to call model functions:

```
$this->User_model->insert_item();
```

When you use this `$this->load->model('User_model');` statement to load the model, CodeIgniter automatically create member variable with that name. So, you can use that member variable to call model functions.